# aptitude current status warning

Tags: linux, apt, aptitude

After installing some packages, i.e. sudo aptitude install pkg ... , there was a line of message at the end of the output:

```
    Current status: 0 updates [-66].
```

What does it mean?

Comment: See also [What is the meaning of the output from “aptitude safe-upgrade”?](http://serverfault.com/questions/482067/what-does-14-mean-in-the-output-from-aptitude-safe-upgrade)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that there are now no updates, which is 66 fewer than there were last time you looked.  In other words, you've most probably just updated 66 packages.